# Title drops down to second line

Tags: html, css

When trying to put an image and a title in a list tag, the title drops to the second line. Is there a way to work around this?

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#searchImg {
   width: 50px;
   height: 72px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
#searchTitle {
   margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p></a></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: You could replace `<p>` with `<span>`. If you want to do more research, try searching for `html inline`.

Comment: You are using block element which spans full width,so use display:inline for block element or use inline element

Comment: Remove margin left and add display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow the following code and you will have the desired result.**

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#searchImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
#searchTitle {
  margin-left: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p></a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using block element(p) which spans **full width**,so use `display:inline` property on block element or simply use Inline elements

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#searchImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#searchTitle {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg">
      <p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg">
      <p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg">
      <p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg">
      <p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aligajani/grsex9xe/)

You have to make it inline using the following.

```
ul p {
  display:inline;
}
```

Gives you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block
```

can help you

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#searchImg {
 width: 50px;
 height: 72px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#searchTitle {
     margin-left: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p></a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align title with the image use `display:inline-block` property.

```
#searchImg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle; // align text to middle of image for better view
}
#searchTitle {
    margin-left: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li
{
}
#searchImg {
 width: 50px;
 height: 72px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#searchTitle {
 display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
       <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p></a></li>  
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using display table to parent and table-cell to child elements

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        ul li a {
            display: table;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        ul li a img, ul li a p {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        #searchImg {
            width: 50px;
            height: 72px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        #searchTitle {
            margin-left: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="myUL">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg">
                <p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg">
                <p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg">
                <p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg">
                <p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#searchImg {
 padding: 0;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 margin-right:10px;
}
#searchTitle {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 display:inline-block;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/2/75533.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">A Certain Magical Index</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/77968.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Ajin</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/22061.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Angel Beats!</p></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/47347.jpg" id="searchImg"><p id="searchTitle">Attack on Titan</p></a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing float: left; property of the **img** and **p** tag. Use the following given CSS for the desired output:

```
ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#searchImg{
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
#searchTitle{
    margin-left: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```